# Asterisk 13 , agi 'DIALSTATUS' not work

Tags: php, asterisk, agi

i was setup a new Rasperry Pi 3 Plus with Stretch, php7 and Asterisk 13 via apt-get etc...

so i have a problem with that

```
 $agi->get_variable('DIALSTATUS');
```

i got a no usefull data

some like this with print_r

```
Array([code] => 200,[result] => 1,[data] =>)
```

or i get

```
 Array([code] => 510,[result] => -1,[data] =>)
```

is there is fix for that or is phpagi for Asterisk 13 obsolet in some Funktions?

On my old Working Pi with Jessy and Asterisk 11.13.1 ist that working for me.

```
<SIP/2000-0000006c>AGI Tx >> 200 result=-1
<SIP/2000-0000006c>AGI Rx << GET VARIABLE DIALSTATUS
<SIP/2000-0000006c>AGI Tx >> 200 result=1 (ANSWER)
<SIP/2000-0000006c>AGI Rx << DialStatus : Invalid or unknown command 
<SIP/2000-0000006c>AGI Rx << print_r : Array
<SIP/2000-0000006c>AGI Rx << (
<SIP/2000-0000006c>AGI Rx <<     [code] => 510
<SIP/2000-0000006c>AGI Rx <<     [result] =>
<SIP/2000-0000006c>AGI Rx <<     [data] => Invalid or unknown command
<SIP/2000-0000006c>AGI Rx << )
<SIP/2000-0000006c>AGI Rx <<
<SIP/2000-0000006c>AGI Rx <<
```

my Temporary fix is for me that at the Moment...

```
[Macro-Dial-Trunk]
exten => s,1,Verbose(--->>>Debug:DoCall agi );
exten => s,n,AGI(_Extention_Dial_000.agi,${ARG1},${ARG2},${ARG3},${ARG4})
exten => s,n,Verbose(0,DIALSTATUS:${DIALSTATUS})
exten => s,n,Set(ARG5=${DIALSTATUS})    
exten =>     s,n,AGI(_Extention_Dial_000.agi,${ARG1},${ARG2},${ARG3},${ARG4},${ARG5})
exten => s,n,hangup()
```

Somone any Idea ???

Will be nice to get help...

Answer (score 0):

DIALSTATUS will be set only after Dial command executed.

You can check what exactly agi do using

```
asterisk -r
agi set debug on
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe, you can use channel_status function.

```
$agi->channel_status()
```

https://www.voip-info.org/channel-status